# Lie differentiation operation for manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

> Let $S^1$ be the unit sphere $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $X=S^1\times S^1\in\mathbb{R}^4$ with defining equations $f_1=x_1^2+x_2^2-1=0, f_2=x_3^2+x_4^2-1=0$. Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $w$ be the vector field $$w=x_1\frac\partial{\partial x_2}-x_2\frac\partial{\partial x_1}+\lambda\left(x_4\frac\partial{\partial x_3}-x_3\frac\partial{\partial x_4}\right)$$ Show that $L_wf_1=0$ and $L_wf_2=0$, where $L_w$ is the Lie differentiation operation.

The definitions in the notes I'm working with are quite badly arranged, so I could be misunderstanding things. If so, please correct me.

I believe $L_wf_1(p)$ means $d(f_1)_p(w(p))$. Basically, the vector $w(p)$ is being mapped to $Df_1(p)w(p)$, where $Df_1(p)$ is the derivative of $f_1$ evaluated at $p$, and that's multiplied by the vector $w(p)$.

Now, I'm quite confused how $Df_1$ would be defined, since $f_1$ is not even as a function as it is (it just specifies the points for which $x_1^2+x_2^2-1=0$.

Comment: Is $f_1: \mathbb R^4 \to\mathbb R$, $f_1 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1$?

Comment: @John I'll be honest and say I don't know. What I typed is what's in the notes I have. If you think your suggestion makes the problem correct, please go ahead and explain why.

Comment: If this is true, then the assertion is correct. The hint is that $w$ is always tangent to $X$.

Comment: Of course, you can also check by definition that $L_wf_1=0$.

Comment: @John Interesting. An earlier part of the exercise asks that $w$ is tangent to $X$, which I did. But how would that imply $L_wf_1=0$? There's definitely something I'm missing. (This is the first time I see the $L_w$ thing, so please pardon my ignorance.)

Comment: The idea is that $df_1$ and $df_2$ are always normal to $X$, as $w$ is tangent to $X$, then $L_w f_i = \langle df_i, w\rangle = 0$.

Comment: @John I believe we have $df_1=(2x_1 2x_2 0 0)$ here. Why is it always normal to $X$?

Comment: Think of $\mathbb S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$ defined by $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$. Then the vector $(x_1, x_2)$ is always normal to the sphere (The position vector is normal to the circle). You can make it rigorous, but in this case I think it is obvious.

Comment: @John Okay. And may I ask why $L_wf_i=\langle df_i,w\rangle =0$? It doesn't seem to match the definition of $L_wf_i$ I used in my post.

Comment: $L_w f_i = df_i(w)$ and if you calculate the RHS, it is just $\langle df_i, w\rangle$.